# Size of macro type?

Tags: c++, macros

I wanted to know what is the maximum number I could type with in a macro expression, until it overflowed. I wrote the following program:

```
#define I (INT_MAX + 1)
#define J (LONG_MAX + 1)

int main()
{
    cout << INT_MAX << I  << endl;
    cout << LONG_MAX << J << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
2147483647-2147483648
9223372036854775807-9223372036854775808
```

I don't understand the overflow for the int case, if it can store a value of LONG_MAX. Also then I remembered that macros can also store decimals like 3.14 (PI), so it should be a float type.
I am now confused. Please help.

Comment: Macros aren't variables. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace. They're instructions for the preprocessor to simply replace all occurrences of the macro name with it's "value".

Comment: Then why is INT_MAX + 1 (= J) overflowing, but LONG_MAX not overflowing?

Comment: Like I said the preprocessor replaces every occurrence of the macro with the text that follows it. So your first print line turns into `cout << INT_MAX << (INT_MAX + 1) << endl;` and your second line turns into `cout << LONG_MAX << (LONG_MAX + 1) << endl;`.

Comment: Also, signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, to technically your program can do anything.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. So LONG_MAX and LONG_MAX + 1 should be printed. LONG_MAX is a macro defined in limits.h as 9223372036854775807. So that is furhter replaced as : cout << 9223372036854775807 << (9223372036854775807 + 1) << endl; - my question is WHY does the second argument overflow? How do we know which type of the expression to take?

Comment: The `LONG_MAX` macro is a `long` literal containing the maximum value of a `long`, so adding one to it overflows. Same with `INT_MAX`. I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: @Kaind you're missing that it is undefined behaviour  . So there is nothing which "should be printed"

Comment: I'm confused as to why LONG_MAX is a 'long' literal - because LONG_MAX is defined as :
#define LONG_MAX 9223372036854775807
There is no mention of the keyword long here, so how can the compiler tell if that number is a long literal or not? (If it's because it won't fit in an integer literal, then why isn't it taken as a LONG LONG literal?)

Comment: It **is not**  #define LONG_MAX 9223372036854775807, it is  #define LONG_MAX 9223372036854775807**L**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros do not have a type. They do not interact with the type system at all. Macros are part of a pre-processing step that is performed before compilation. Macros are **textual replacement**. After your source has been pre-processed, the result seen by the compiler is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    cout << INT_MAX << (INT_MAX + 1)  << endl;
    cout << LONG_MAX << (LONG_MAX + 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

... except `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX` are themselves macros, so they would have been expanded to some integer literal as part of the pre-processing as well. The exact values are implementation specific and can differ between systems, so I did not expand them here in order for the answer remain general.

P.S. The behaviour of the program is undefined, because of signed overflow.